# Generating Invoice & Capture Online Payment In Loop

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.6

I have the same problem, but this only happens when I try to generate invoices in Loop. The first transaction creates an invoice & transaction in DB but when I attempt to capture payment ( ONLINE ) in the loop for second order, the system generates invoices correctly. Still, when I save the order to Generate a Capture Transaction in Db, the system gives me an error.

```
{"error":"Set order for existing transactions not allowed"}
```

Code

```
private function processNewInvoice(Order $order, array $items, $amount, $pendingInvoice, $id): Invoice|bool
{
    try {
        $this->_logger->info('Invoice Creation', ['invoice' => $pendingInvoice . '-' . $order->getEntityId()]);

        $newInvoice = $order->prepareInvoice($items);

        $newInvoice->setGrandTotal($amount);

        $newInvoice->setData('ora_invoice_number', $pendingInvoice);

        $newInvoice->setBaseGrandTotal($amount);

        $this->_logger->info('Invoice to be processed', ['invoice' => $newInvoice->getData()]);

        if (!$newInvoice->getTotalQty()) {
            $this->_logger->debug('Cannot create an invoice without products for order ' . $order->getIncrementId());
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Cannot create an invoice without products'));
        }

        $newInvoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Invoice::CAPTURE_ONLINE);

        $newInvoice->register();

        $newInvoice->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);

        $newInvoice->save();

        //Create Transaction
        $transaction = $this->transactionFactory->create()
            ->addObject($newInvoice)
            ->addObject($order);
        $transaction->save();

        $comment = 'Amount of $' . number_format($newInvoice->getGrandTotal(), 2) . '. Transaction ID: "' . $newInvoice->getTransactionId() . '"';
        $order->addCommentToStatusHistory($comment)->save();

    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        $this->_logger->critical('Cannot create invoice', ['error' => $exception->getMessage()]);
    }

    $this->_logger->info('Invoice Saved and captured', ['invoice' => $newInvoice->getId()]);

    return $newInvoice;
}
```